# Is there an Autohotkey alternative for Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: linux, debian, script, autohotkey, raspberry-pi

Bought a Raspberry Pi 3 (Raspbian OS) but sadly, autohotkey cannot be installed on it and .exe files aren't supported either. Is there an alternative to autohotkey that works on Raspberry pi 3 maybe?

Looking for something that automatically opens the browser, enters a specific link and clicks specific coordinates with mouse, all in an endless loop.

That's possible?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: Also, it would be better if this were describing what you actually want to do. For example, I assume you are testing a website? There are better ways to do that than using a GUI automator.

Comment: Can you give examples of that ways pls?

Comment: Describe your actual issue first, then we may be able to suggest some solutions. Not the other way around. See [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/267029).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up Selenium, or more specifically, Selenium for Raspberry Pi

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027385/using-selenium-on-raspberry-pi-headless